# Qt - module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I get the above error when trying to compile my Qt project from Qt Creator. Can I change the target machine type to x64 somewhere?

When I convert the project to a VC++ project from the command line, it builds and runs. This is good enough, but it would be convenient to be able to build and run directly from the Qt Creator.

Does this result from Qt being 32 bit and other components being 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

The 32/64-bit build of Qt must correspond to the Visual Studio project settings of your project. Remember that it is perfectly normal to have multiple (perhaps dozens) of Qt builds existing side-by-side on a given development system. The particular project you're building should use the Qt build that is compatible with it: the Visual Studio versions and 32/64-bit choices must agree.

Note that VS2015 Update 3 is binary compatible with VS2017. Otherwise, C++ code built with mismatched Visual Studio major releases is not binary compatible (won't link or will crash on startup).

Comment: Using Visual Studio, the project builds and runs perfectly. The problem is with Qt Creator. (I'm not sure I understand your answer correctly.)

Comment: Qt Creator uses an installation of Qt that you chose, and the compiler that you chose, to build your project. All of these elements must match. If you didn't choose any of them, then the defaults don't work for you and you must make additional choices yourself. Go to Creator's "Build and Run" pane, then ensure you have the right entries added to Compilers, Qt Versions and Kits. And finally, ensure that you select the right kit for your project. Note that Qt Creator is not a compiler, but Visual Studio is several compilers and also an IDE.